# Java Long Comparison

Tags: java, android, comparison, long-integer

**Introduction**: I have a method in Android for doing Long comparisons. Basically, I compare dates (timestamps/epochs). One of these comparisons checks if dates are equal "if (a2 == a1 && b2 == b1)".

**Problem**: The problem is that even when these numbers are equal, the "if" does not work. I am also attaching a screenshot from the debugging screen with the values that are being compared in an example.

**Question**: Would you know why the condition is not working? I can't figure since it is just math that should work. Maybe there is a casting issue that I am not seeing? All other cases the "if" works.

**Method**:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getConflicts(ArrayList<AssetBooking> assetBookings) {

        Epoch epoch = new Epoch();
        ArrayList<Integer> conflicts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (AssetBooking aB : assetBookings) {

            Long a1 = aB.getFromDatetime() / 1000;
            Long b1 = aB.getToDatetime() / 1000;

            Long a2 = epoch.getEpochNoSeconds(fromDatetime);
            Long b2 = epoch.getEpochNoSeconds(toDatetime);

            if (a2 == a1 && b2 == b1) {
                System.out.println("equals");
            }

            if ((a2 < a1 && b2 >= a1) || (a2 == a1) || (a2 > a1 && b2 < b1) || (a2 > a1 && a2 < b1) || (a2 == a1 && b2 == b1)) {
                conflicts.add(assetBookings.indexOf(aB));
            }

        }

        return conflicts;

    }
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: try primitive type "long" instead of "Long" which is a wrapper class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Long` is an object. if you type `a1 == a2` you check if a1 is a2 - the same object, not the same value. If you want to compare it, you have to write `a1.equals(a2)` - as in `String`.

If you really do not need `Long`, use `long` - it will be easier and can be more efiicient

Comment: It worked... Can you help me to understand why people keep down voting my question? This is a great platform but people just down vote, I had care to write it. My other account I can't post questions anymore because people keep doing this. Aff. I don't know the point of the platform if people can't ask stuff they don't know...

Comment: I think minus votes are because question is not related to Android, but to Java, and compariosn and equality of object and primitives is basic subject in Java learning. You probably will get faster response by searching in Google or in any book

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
long a1,a2;
long b1,b2;

if (a2.equals(a1) && b2.equals(b1)) {

}
```